# Using CompleteableFuture for executing two methods async

Tags: java, asynchronous

here is snippet of the code I have to make run faster:

```
fillPricedServiceForLocation(location, doc, locale, services);

fillReviewsForLocation(location, doc, services);
```

Two methods look as follows:

```
private static void fillPricedServiceForLocation(Location location, LocationDocument doc,
    Language locale, List<Long> services) {
    if (doc.isPriceList()) {
        String locationId = doc.getLocationId();
        try {
            new PricesRepository().findServiceForLocation(locationId, services)
                .ifPresent(foundService -> {
                    String serviceId = foundService.getServiceId();
                    final LocationServices locationServices = new LocationServices();
                    locationServices.setId(Integer.valueOf(serviceId));
                    locationServices.setPrice(BigDecimal.valueOf(foundService.getPrice()));
                    locationServices.setCurrency(foundService.getCurrency());

                    ServiceName serviceName = ServiceNameProvider.getServiceName(serviceId);
                    locationServices.setName(serviceName.getName(locale));
                    location.setServices(locationServices);
                });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error when trying to retrieve last review for location {}", locationId,
                      e);

        }
    }
}

private static void fillReviewsForLocation(Location location, LocationDocument doc,
    List<Long> services) {
    String locationId = doc.getLocationId();
    try {
        LocationReviews locationReviews = new LocationReviews();
        locationReviews.setCount(doc.getReviewsCount());
        locationReviews.setScore(doc.getReviewsScore());

        new ReviewsRepository().findReview(locationId, services).ifPresent(
            foundReview -> locationReviews.setReview(reviewDocumentToJsonModel(foundReview)));
        location.setReviews(locationReviews);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error when trying to retrieve last review for location {}", locationId, e);
    }
}
```

They make calls to two different repositiories and if they find something they process it and update passed as argument **location**. Is it possible to paralelize those two method calls so they are processed at the same time? Tried using CompleteableFuture but wasn't able to make it run - don't have much experience with async programming.

Comment: For that `location.setServices` need to provide synchronization (handle parallel writes)

Answer (score 0):

YOu can two different threads and in run() method of each thread write one function.Then use ExecutorService.submit(threadOne) and ExecutorService.submit(threadTwo) to execute it in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

With CompletableFutures you should be able to just do:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> task1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> fillPricedServiceForLocation(location, doc, locale, services));

CompletableFuture<Void> task2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> fillReviewsForLocation(location, doc, services)));

task1.join();
task2.join();
```

This will run both tasks in parallel, in new separate threads (the default fork-join pool used for these things by the JVM). The main thread will wait for both to finish (with the `join()`. You can do other things before calling `join()` if you like too.

If both are updating the same object (`Location`), make sure your updates are thread safe. It might be safer to have the methods return the information separately and then updating the common data structure in the main thread. This would also be faster than introducing unnecessary `synchronized` blocks.

If you want to return some value from the `CompletableFuture` you can easily do it by using `supplyAsync()` instead of `runAsync()` which allows you to return the value to the task. (Its type won't be `CompletableFuture<Void>` but `CompletableFuture<LocationReviews>` and `CompletableFuture<LocationServices>`.)

So for example, instead the methods could be like this:

```
CompletableFuture<LocationServices> servicesTask = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getPricedServiceForLocation(doc, locale, services));

CompletableFuture<LocationReviews> reviewsTask = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getReviewsForLocation(doc, services)));

location.setServices(servicesTask.get());
location.setReviews(reviewsTask.get());
```

You don't need to pass the Location as an argument to those methods, they will just retrieve the information for you asynchronously.

```
private static LocationServices getPricedServiceForLocation(LocationDocument doc, Language locale, List<Long> services) {
  ...
}

private static LocationReviews getReviewsForLocation(LocationDocument doc, List<Long> services) {
  ...
}
```